# d3 .data key initially comes back undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use the optional key function when binding data in d3. I have a local test data set and I am trying to use the "title" property of each object as the key.

The key function seems to be running 4 times when I only have 3 objects in my data array. In the d3 documentation is says that the data key function may be called multiple times when binding the data, I just don't understand what I am doing wrong.

**This is my object and a few lines of code (I am using 'console.log(i)' to illustrate my confusion):**

```
test:[
  {
    "desc":"This it the first test description text.",
    "image":"test1.jpg",
    "title":"Test Project 1"
  },
  {
    "desc":"This is the second test decription text.",
    "image":"test2.jpg",
    "title":"Test Project 2"
  },
  {
    "desc":"This is the third test decription text.",
    "image":"test3.jpg",
    "title":"Test Project 3"
  }
]  

console.log(obj.testJSON.test[0].title);   //line 178
console.log(obj.testJSON.test);   //line 179

d3.selectAll(".slider-image")
 .data(obj.testJSON.test, function(d,i) {console.log(i); return d; });   //line 182
```

**That gives me this output in the console:**

[image: console output of d3.key]

**When trying to console.log 'd' instead of 'i':**

```
 .data(obj.testJSON.test, function(d,i) {console.log(d); return d; });   //line 182
```

**the first log is undefined:**

[image]

**When I try to actually set the key how I think it should be:**

```
  d3.selectAll(".slider-image")
   .data(obj.testJSON.test, function(d) {return d.title; });
  }
```

**I get a type error on the first call to the key function:**

```
 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined'
```

Comment: The error occurs only when you have elements of class "slider-image" that have no data bound to them. In that case it doesn't make sense to have a key function anyway -- you should first bind data to all elements you want to work with and then do selections and data matching with key functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand it, when you run `data()` with a key function, it does the following:

1. Runs the key function on each of the nodes in the selection you're calling `data()` on.
2. Runs the key function on each of the data values that you passed to `data()` as the first argument.
3. Matches up the results. Nodes in the original selection without a match in the data values become part of the `exit()` selection (because you often want to get rid of them). Data values that don't match any of the nodes in the original selection go into the `enter()` selection (because you need to create nodes for them if you want to do anything with them). Data values that match up nodes in the original selection are bound to those nodes, which are placed in the `update()` selection.

In order for this to work, you need key to be a function that will work on both the nodes in the original selection and on your new data values.

My guess as to what's going on is that `d3.selectAll(".slider-image")` is either empty, or only contains a node that doesn't have any data bound to it previously. So the key function gets run on it, returns undefined, and then gets run on each of your incoming data values. When you ask for the title attribute of of the original selection's data, it throws an error, because it doesn't have any data. It's probably hard to use a key function effectively if your selection doesn't currently have any data bound to it (although you could maybe do something with indices), so I'm guessing your use case isn't what the key function was intended for.

Comment: This is my problem, however I am trying to set the selection's original data with a key. Should I bind the data to the object, then use the key function when I go to update?

Comment: Yes - I'm pretty sure the key function is only intended for updating selections that already have data bound to them. Is there some reason you need to bind your first set of data in a specific order?

Comment: I think my problem is I already added my first ".slider-image" to the DOM using pure javascript before trying to bind the data with the key function. I think if it isn't already in the DOM then the key function will only be called 3 times for the 3 data values. Then I can use enter() to add the element(s).
I should have said that in the original post. I still don't know if I need to use the key function...I will have to try not adding it to the DOM before the data bind.

Comment: You definitely don't need to key function if all you want do is bind a .slider-image for each value.